# WCF Polymorphism in service contract

Tags: wcf, serialization, polymorphism

I am trying to create a service that with an operation that accepts, as a parameter, an any object that implements a specific interface. I would have thought this would be easy to accomplish, but I am running into problems (what I am guessing to be serialization problems but I am not certain). I have the following contract:

```
//Unsustainable because I would need a method for each of the (currently)
//3 student types, plus I have 2 more root categories that have multiple subtypes
public interface IEmailTemplateAccess
{

    [FaultContract(typeof(ValidationFault))]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ErrorResponse))]
    [OperationContract]
    [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]
    TemplateResponse GetStudentTemplate(ITemplateRequest request);

}
```

And this is what I would like it to look like:

```
public interface IEmailTemplateAccess
{

    [FaultContract(typeof(ValidationFault))]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ErrorResponse))]
    [OperationContract]
    [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]
    TemplateResponse GetTemplate(ITemplateRequest request);

}
```

In my service I use an abstract factory to return the correct template based on the type of request that comes in. In addition, I have created concrete ITemplateRequests for the different kinds of templates that could be returned. For example, I have Template Request types A and B. Template Request Type A can have one of 3 sub types, SubType1, SubType2 and SubType3. I then created a SubType3 request that implemented the ITemplateRequest interface (SubType3Request).

I would hate to have to create a method for each request type I have (i.e. GetSubType1Template, GetSubType2Template, GetSubType3Template, GetTypeBTemplate, etc) as this would quickly become unwieldy as the types of templates I can get will be changing occasionally.

Is there a way to have a contract method accept anything that implements ITemplateRequest as a parameter and let my factory do the work of figuring out what type of template to get?

So far, I have the following methods in my service:

```
    //Not a part of the contract right now although I would like it to be
    public IEmailTemplate GetTemplate(ITemplateRequest request)
    {
        TemplateFactoryBuilder builder = new TemplateFactoryBuilder();
        ITemplateFactory factory = builder.GetTemplateFactory(request.Type);
        var template = factory.GetTemplate(request);
        return template;
    }

    //contract method --This would be my Parent Request Type (RequestTypeA) from above. 
    //There are 3 subtypes of the Student type
    public TemplateResponse GetStudentTemplate(StudentEmailTemplateRequest request)
    {
        var response = new TemplateResponse
                           {
                               RequiresProcessing = true
                           };


        response.Template = (EmailMergeTemplate) GetTemplate(request);
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the link-ish answer, but it's pretty long.. What you're after (I think) is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/morgan/archive/2009/08/05/polymorphism-in-wcf.aspx

It boils down to using known types. Something like this;

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType("GetKnownTypes", typeof(CommandServiceHelper))]
public interface ICommandService
```